# Image Pixel Wise Transformations - Recommended Order

Tags: image-processing

I'm new in image processing. Right now I know how to correct white balance and how to correct image contrast. But if I need to make this two tranformations. In which order should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried? Also, the math isn't hard – since you said you know how to do it, you should also be able to mathematically concatenate the two, and see whether the result differs (and in which way).

Comment: @Anton, Could you please review my answer? If it works for you, please mark it.

Answer (score 2):

Since both operations are not linear they are not interchangeable.

When Processing RAW Files from Digital Cameras you first create the correct balance between the RGB channels (White Balance) and only then work one effects like contrast.

One could use hands waiving to say that before doing contrast one need to set the correct value of the pixel (White Balance).
There is a logic to that but it is not derived from a Physical law or Mathematical truth.